# How to disable time display on custom time bar hover in vis timeline?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have some custom bars in my vis timeline. But as we hover over the bars, it shows the custom time of that marker. Is there a way I can disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
timeline.setCustomTimeTitle('');
```

And this will disable the hover over custome time marker.